# Create a map that differentiates clusters by different colors

Tags: r, ggplot2, cluster-analysis, raster, rgdal

I'm going to insert two code below that do the same thing. I did this because in one I used the `raster` function to generate the map and another using the `ggplot` function. One of these code might be easier to help resolve this issue. The idea of these codes is to generate a map with points, and these points are distinguished by the cluster in which they are part. The clusters are differentiated by different colors, as you can see in the generated outputs. In this case, I have two clusters, which are: 1 and 2. However, I would not like to differentiate the points as I did, but I would like to show different colors in the regions of the clusters, according to this example of the map below, which represents the idea what i want.

Notice on the map that the cluster 1 region is in green and the cluster 2 region is in blue. So it's something similar to what I want to do. Can you help me?

**Similar map of what I want :**

[image]

**First code:**

```
    library(rgdal)
    library(sf)
    library(raster)
    library (dplyr)
    
    temp <- tempfile()
    temp2 <- tempfile()
    download.file("https://geoftp.ibge.gov.br/organizacao_do_territorio/malhas_territoriais/malhas_municipais/municipio_2015/UFs/PR/pr_municipios.zip",temp)
    
    
    unzip(zipfile = temp, exdir = temp2)
    shp <- readOGR(temp2)
    shp_subset <- shp[shp$NM_MUNICIP == "CASTRO",]
    
    #Points
   Points_properties<-structure(list(Latitude = c(-24.781624, -24.775017, -24.769196, 
     -24.761741, -24.752019, -24.748008, -24.737312, -24.744718, -24.751996, 
     -24.724589, -24.8004, -24.796899, -24.795041, -24.780501, -24.763376, 
     -24.801715, -24.728005, -24.737845, -24.743485, -24.742601, -24.766422, 
     -24.767525, -24.775631, -24.792703, -24.790994, -24.787275, -24.795902, 
     -24.785587, -24.787558, -24.799524), Longitude = c(-49.937369, 
     -49.950576, -49.927608, -49.92762, -49.920608, -49.927707, -49.922095, 
     -49.915438, -49.910843, -49.899478, -49.901775, -49.89364, -49.925657, 
     -49.893193, -49.94081, -49.911967, -49.893358, -49.903904, -49.906435, 
     -49.927951, -49.939603, -49.941541, -49.94455, -49.929797, -49.92141, 
     -49.915141, -49.91042, -49.904772, -49.894034, -49.86651), cluster = c("1", "1", 
     "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
     "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
     "1", "1")), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
     "data.frame"))
    
#Generate map

marsize <- .2
par(mar = rep(marsize,4))
z <- .4
shp_subset_cropped <- raster::crop(shp_subset,
                                   extent(c(
                                     (extent(shp_subset)@"xmin"*(1-z)+z*min(Points_properties$Longitude)),
                                     (extent(shp_subset)@"xmax"*(1-z)+z*max(Points_properties$Longitude)),
                                     (extent(shp_subset)@"ymin"*(1-z)+z*min(Points_properties$Latitude)),
                                     (extent(shp_subset)@"ymax"*(1-z)+z*max(Points_properties$Latitude))
                                   )))
plot(shp_subset_cropped)

pp1 <- filter(Points_properties,
          cluster==1)

pp2 <- filter(Points_properties,
          cluster==2)

points(x = pp1$Longitude,
       y= pp1$Latitude, col = "red",pch = 16,cex=1)
points(x = pp2$Longitude,
       y= pp2$Latitude, col = "blue",pch = 16,cex=1)
```

**Generated output 1**

[image: [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1tiV.png]

**Second code:**

```
library(rgdal)
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)

temp <- tempfile()
temp2 <- tempfile()
download.file("https://geoftp.ibge.gov.br/organizacao_do_territorio/malhas_territoriais/malhas_municipais/municipio_2015/UFs/PR/pr_municipios.zip",temp)
unzip(zipfile = temp, exdir = temp2)
shp <- sf::read_sf(temp2)
shp_subset <- shp[shp$NM_MUNICIP == "CASTRO",]



#Points
Points_properties<-structure(list(Latitude = c(-24.781624, -24.775017, -24.769196, 
                                               -24.761741, -24.752019, -24.748008, -24.737312, -24.744718, -24.751996, 
                                               -24.724589, -24.8004, -24.796899, -24.795041, -24.780501, -24.763376, 
                                               -24.801715, -24.728005, -24.737845, -24.743485, -24.742601, -24.766422, 
                                               -24.767525, -24.775631, -24.792703, -24.790994, -24.787275, -24.795902, 
                                               -24.785587, -24.787558, -24.799524), Longitude = c(-49.937369, 
                                               -49.950576, -49.927608, -49.92762, -49.920608, -49.927707, -49.922095, 
                                               -49.915438, -49.910843, -49.899478, -49.901775, -49.89364, -49.925657, 
                                               -49.893193, -49.94081, -49.911967, -49.893358, -49.903904, -49.906435, 
                                               -49.927951, -49.939603, -49.941541, -49.94455, -49.929797, -49.92141, 
                                               -49.915141, -49.91042, -49.904772, -49.894034, -49.86651), 
                                               cluster = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
                                               "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
                                               "1", "1")), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = "data.frame")


#Generate map
ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = shp_subset, aes()) +
  geom_point(data = Points_properties, 
             aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, color = cluster))+
  coord_sf(xlim = c(min(Points_properties$Longitude)-0.1,
                    max(Points_properties$Longitude)+0.1),
           ylim = c(min(Points_properties$Latitude)-0.1,
                    max(Points_properties$Latitude)+0.1),
           expand = FALSE) +
theme_void()
```

**Generated output 2**

[image]

**Map generated by Phil code**

[image]

Comment: Its not clear to me exactly what you want. Do you want a way to split your polygon in your final plot into two based on the attribute value of the points, so you can then draw something like the figure headed "(b)" in your first image?

Comment: Exactly, @Spacedman! My main idea is to differentiate by different colors the regions of the clusters, therefore, cluster region 1 is one color and cluster region 2 is another color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `terra` (the replacement of `raster`)

Your example data

```
library(terra)
brz <- geodata::gadm("Brazil", level=2, path=".")
mun <- brz[brz$NAME_2 == "Castro", ]

pdata <- data.frame(Latitude = c(-24.781624, -24.775017, -24.769196, -24.761741, -24.752019, -24.748008, -24.737312, -24.744718, -24.751996, -24.724589, -24.8004, -24.796899, -24.795041, -24.780501, -24.763376, -24.801715, -24.728005, -24.737845, -24.743485, -24.742601, -24.766422, -24.767525, -24.775631, -24.792703, -24.790994, -24.787275, -24.795902, -24.785587, -24.787558, -24.799524), 
   Longitude = c(-49.937369, -49.950576, -49.927608, -49.92762, -49.920608, -49.927707, -49.922095, -49.915438, -49.910843, -49.899478, -49.901775, -49.89364, -49.925657, -49.893193, -49.94081, -49.911967, -49.893358, -49.903904, -49.906435, -49.927951, -49.939603, -49.941541, -49.94455, -49.929797, -49.92141, -49.915141, -49.91042, -49.904772, -49.894034, -49.86651), 
   cluster = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"))
   
pts <- vect(data.frame(pdata), c("Longitude", "Latitude"))
```

Create a Voronoi diagram for the extent of the municipality, aggregate it, and remove areas outside the municipality (I am guessing that is what you want)

```
z <- voronoi(pts, mun) 
z <- aggregate(z, "cluster")
z <- crop(z, mun)
```

Now plot

```
plot(z, "cluster", col=c("blue", "green"), mar=0,
   plg=list(x=-50.213, y=-24.889, title="Cluster"), main="", axes=FALSE)
points(pts, col="red", cex=.75)
```

[image]

Some alternatives for the map:

```
plot(z, "cluster", col=c("blue", "green"), main="")
```

Or

```
plot(z, "cluster", col=c("blue", "green"), plg=list(title="Cluster"), main="")
```

Or

```
z$cluster2 <- paste("cluster", z$cluster)
plot(z, "cluster2", col=c("blue", "green"), axes=FALSE, main="")
```

Comment: Thanks @Robert for the reply. Please, how do I remove the x and y coordinates and leave only the map, and also insert cluster 1 and cluster 2 in the legend?

Comment: If you do not want to show the points, then do not add them. I have added some additional examples. There are many other things you can do.

Comment: Thanks Robert, in fact, I didn't want to take the points off the map, and yes, that border x and y that shows the numbers of lat and long.

Comment: Use `axes=FALSE`.  See ?terra::plot --- or ask a new question if that does not help

Answer (score 1):

This is imperfect because the fill extends beyond the boundaries of the shapefile, but it might be useful nonetheless. The trick is to use a voronoi algorithm using `ggraph::geom_node_voronoi()`.

```
library(ggraph)

ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = shp_subset) +
  geom_point(data = Points_properties, 
             aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, color = cluster))+
  geom_node_voronoi(data = Points_properties, bound = c(-50.24633, -49.49878 , -25.07238, -24.541),
                            aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, fill = cluster), alpha = 0.2) +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(min(Points_properties$Longitude)-0.1,
                    max(Points_properties$Longitude)+0.1),
           ylim = c(min(Points_properties$Latitude)-0.1,
                    max(Points_properties$Latitude)+0.1),
           expand = FALSE) +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Phil, I used your code but the map looks different, please have a look at the question, I put the map generated using your code.

Comment: This is based on the vector fed in to the `bound` argument in `geom_node_voronoi()`. Take a look at the minimum and maximum coordinates of `shp_subset` and change the vector to that, based on the following format: `c(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)`.

Answer (score 1):

I present here another approach using `sf` based on the Voronoi idea. With `st_voronoi()` I generated all the voronoi polygons based on every point and after I have to perform the "point-in-polygon" exercise to assign the cluster to each polygon. After that, I intersect that object with the initial region to get the final shape:

```r
temp <- tempfile()
temp2 <- tempfile()
download.file("https://geoftp.ibge.gov.br/organizacao_do_territorio/malhas_territoriais/malhas_municipais/municipio_2015/UFs/PR/pr_municipios.zip", temp)


unzip(zipfile = temp, exdir = temp2)

library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

shp <- st_read(temp2)
#> Simple feature collection with 399 features and 2 fields
#> Geometry type: POLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -54.6193 ymin: -26.71712 xmax: -48.02354 ymax: -22.5163
#> Geodetic CRS:  SIRGAS 2000

shp_subset <- shp %>% filter(NM_MUNICIP == "CASTRO")

# Points
Points_properties <- structure(list(Latitude = c(
  -24.781624, -24.775017, -24.769196,
  -24.761741, -24.752019, -24.748008, -24.737312, -24.744718, -24.751996,
  -24.724589, -24.8004, -24.796899, -24.795041, -24.780501, -24.763376,
  -24.801715, -24.728005, -24.737845, -24.743485, -24.742601, -24.766422,
  -24.767525, -24.775631, -24.792703, -24.790994, -24.787275, -24.795902,
  -24.785587, -24.787558, -24.799524
), Longitude = c(
  -49.937369,
  -49.950576, -49.927608, -49.92762, -49.920608, -49.927707, -49.922095,
  -49.915438, -49.910843, -49.899478, -49.901775, -49.89364, -49.925657,
  -49.893193, -49.94081, -49.911967, -49.893358, -49.903904, -49.906435,
  -49.927951, -49.939603, -49.941541, -49.94455, -49.929797, -49.92141,
  -49.915141, -49.91042, -49.904772, -49.894034, -49.86651
), cluster = c(
  "1", "1",
  "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1",
  "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1",
  "1", "1"
)), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c(
  "tbl_df", "tbl",
  "data.frame"
))


# Convert points to sf

points_sf <- st_as_sf(Points_properties, coords = c("Longitude", "Latitude"), crs = 4326)


ggplot(shp_subset) +
  geom_sf() +
  geom_sf(data = points_sf)
```

[image]

```r
# Voronoi approach
pols <- points_sf %>%
  st_union() %>%
  st_voronoi(envelope = st_geometry(shp_subset)) %>%
  st_collection_extract("POLYGON") %>%
  st_sf(x = 1)
#> Warning in st_voronoi.sfc(., envelope = st_geometry(shp_subset)): st_voronoi
#> does not correctly triangulate longitude/latitude data

ggplot(pols) +
  geom_sf() +
  geom_sf(data = points_sf)
```

[image]

```r
# Perform point in polygon and merge the clusters

final <- pols %>%
  st_join(points_sf) %>%
  group_by(cluster) %>%
  summarise(a = 1) %>%
  st_transform(st_crs(shp_subset)) %>%
  # Intersect with original geometry
  st_intersection(shp_subset)
#> Warning: attribute variables are assumed to be spatially constant throughout all
#> geometries

ggplot(final) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = cluster), alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_sf(data = points_sf, aes(color = cluster)) +
  theme_void() +
  coord_sf(
    xlim = c(
      min(Points_properties$Longitude) - 0.1,
      max(Points_properties$Longitude) + 0.1
    ),
    ylim = c(
      min(Points_properties$Latitude) - 0.1,
      max(Points_properties$Latitude) + 0.1
    ),
    expand = FALSE
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>