# Problems viewing shapefile in R

Tags: r, r-sf

I'm having problems with viewing a shapefile and would like your help with this. In this file (https://encurtador.com.br/ivKS2) is the Brazilian pipeline, but I would like to check how I can view this from R. The file is in zip format.

I did as follows:

```
library(rgdal)
library(sf)

temp <- tempfile()
temp2 <- tempfile()
download.file("https://encurtador.com.br/ivKS2",temp)
unzip(zipfile = temp, exdir = temp2)
shp <- sf::read_sf(temp2)
```

But it's going wrong.

**Other link to test:**

https://github.com/JovaniSouza/JovaniSouza5/blob/ac61a729b3856112bcb100f4dfb2c900565fdb54/gasoduto1.zip

Comment: are you 100% certain the zip file is legit? when I try open it it throws an error at ZIP level (bad archive)

Comment: I think that your problem is maybe more related with the way you are using to download and unzip the inputs. Remember that you are working with .shp files which needs to be read together with the auxiliar files. So, the line for download is OK, but the line for unzipping is refering just a file (`temp2`) instead of a directory (a folder for .shp and all the rest of auxiliar files).

Comment: @JindraLacko, in fact, it was as `.rar` file, so I switched to `.zip`, because of the `unzip` function that I inserted above. Could that be why?

Comment: @WenchengLau-Medrano, thanks for the reply! The code above is based on the code of this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72553487/create-a-map-that-differentiates-clusters-by-different-colors So I thought it would work. The auxiliary files are in the `.zip` file, that is, `gasoduto.zip`. If you click on the link, it will download automatically, then you can see that all files are present.

Comment: @Antonio yes, I know, that is why I said that your problem maybe is more related with the unzipping instead of the reading. I have downloaded and unziped your files manually and I read (and plot) them sucsessfully in R (well I see that it is just a line similar to a river section).

Comment: @WenchengLau-Medrano, could you post the code that did this as an answer?

Comment: I inserted another link in the question to see if it works for you. My idea is to plot after using the `unzip` function.

Answer (score 1):

I could read and plot your directory by using:

```
require(sp)
require(rgdal)

gasoducto <- readOGR(dsn = "gasoduto/gasoduto_SIRGAS_2000.shp", 
                     layer = "gasoduto_SIRGAS_2000")

plot(gasoducto)

axis(side = 1)
axis(side = 2)
```